# Funcion con filtros dropdown

Tags: javascript, datatable

Tengo una función que me filtra cada columna de una tabla con un dropdown. Quisiera que tan solo me filtrase las columnas que yo quisiera y que al menos una de ellas filtrase con un datetimepicker (calendario) y no con un dropdown.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  function cbDropdown(column) {
    return $('<ul>', {
      'class': 'cb-dropdown'
    }).appendTo($('<div>', {
      'class': 'cb-dropdown-wrap'
    }).appendTo(column));
  }

  $('#example2').DataTable({
    initComplete: function() {
      this.api().columns().every(function() {
        var column = this;
        var ddmenu = cbDropdown($(column.header()))
          .on('change', ':checkbox', function() {
            var vals = $(':checked', ddmenu).map(function(index, element) {
              return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());
            }).toArray().join('|');

            column
              .search(vals.length > 0 ? '^(' + vals + ')$' : '', true, false)
              .draw();
              //console.log(vals);
              if(vals === ""){
              $(this).parent().parent().parent().removeClass("factive");
              }else{             $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass("factive");
              }
              //change callback
          });

        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
          var // wrapped
            $label = $('<label>'),
            $text = $('<span>', {
              text: d
            }),
            $cb = $('<input>', {
              type: 'checkbox',
              value: d
            });

          $text.appendTo($label);
          $cb.appendTo($label);

          ddmenu.append($('<li>').append($label));
        });
      });


  $(".cb-dropdown-wrap").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).parent().width());
    $(this).width($(this).parent().width());
  });
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

He cambiado esta linea

```
this.api().columns().every( function () {
```

por esta:

```
this.api().columns('.select-filter').every( function () {
```

con esto se soluciona el que en algunas columnas no filtre pero no consigo que en vez de un select salga un calendario para elegir la fecha.